# JOIN and concatenate between tables and UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

The server is SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2017. Probably a simple answer to this one, but it has me a bit stumped.
Ok so I have two tables, one has basic vendor inventory information and the other is a vendor code lookup to match it to our product database.  The vendor inventory is updated nightly from a downloaded XML file so I don't have control over how it comes in sadly.

What I'm needing to do is JOIN the two tables and UPDATE one of the columns with the concatenation of two of the columns from two different tables.

I have the concatenation done:

```
SELECT concat(SFXVencode, partnumber) as Pcode
  FROM KeyInventory JOIN Keybrands
    ON keybrands.vencode = keyinventory.vencode
```

But what I need is the ability to save this into a column in the `keyinventory` table.

So the concatenated `productcode` (what matches to our `product` database) needs to be saved in a column.

This is how far I've gotten, but it's not working currently.

```
UPDATE KeyInventory
SET KeyInventory.Productcode = (

SELECT concat(SFXVencode, partnumber) as Pcode
  FROM KeyInventory JOIN Keybrands
    ON keybrands.vencode = keyinventory.vencode     
        )
```

I'm needing the `KeyInventory.Productcode` to be updated to the `Pcode`

I hope this all makes sense and I would be forever grateful for a fix for this.
KeyBrands

SFXVenCode
            VenCode
        
        
            ACC
            A51

KeyInventory

PartNumber
            VenCode
            ProductCode
        
        
            3102
            A51
            (what I need)

So the Concatenated would be ACC3102 and I need it saved into the KeyInventory table.

Sorry, cannot use html to format the table data.. argh.

Comment: The server is 2008r2 and SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
UPDATE KeyInventory 
SET KeyInventory.Productcode = concat(SFXVencode, partnumber)
FROM KeyInventory 
   INNER JOIN Keybrands ON keybrands.vencode = keyinventory.vencode
```

Might need a little tweaking once you post your DDL...

Comment: @ChrissB You were so close! Please still update your question with data so that this might be useful to others in the future :) [This site](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) might help with formatting sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @LowlyDBA - John M helped me figure the right syntax for MySQL:

```
UPDATE KeyInventory
    SET KeyInventory.Productcode = (SELECT CONCAT(SFXVencode, partnumber)
    FROM KeyInventory as KI
    INNER JOIN Keybrands ON keybrands.vencode = KI.vencode 
    WHERE KeyInventory.vencode = KI.vencode )
```

It has been a while but hopefully this will help others.